# Namespacing in Laravel Spark install

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to install Laravel Spark into an existing app. I have not changed the default namespace of "App".

I get the following error on install:

```
 Class 'Laravel\Spark\Providers\SparkServiceProvider' not found
```

How can get around this error?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions? https://github.com/laravel/spark also, yesterday was it first day, there is a new release https://github.com/laravel/spark/releases

Comment: @MiharbiHernandez I followed the instructions, except for the "create a new laravel instance" bit. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1):

It means you didnt attach a class for laravel to detect it ..

Go to App/Config..open app.php..

scroll down.. youll see a providers list.. add a new line to it like

```
Laravel\Spark\Providers\SparkServiceProvider::class,
```

Save and Try again :)

Comment: The installer puts that line in the config file app.php

Comment: what about aliases tab? i will do an installation and confirm it

Comment: it didnt auto write provider for me.. try removing it from composer and run a composer update.. then re-run -  composer require "laravel/spark-installer=~1.0" and add provider class again

Comment: i tried composer remove and composer global remove, I get the same exception when I run composer update.

Comment: did you get a new config file inside config folder? delete it if you have.. then remove all spark classes from app config,remove spark from composer.json and rerun composer update

Comment: "New config file" is app.pup in config folder, right? (Sorry, I'm still a bit I f a newbie)

Comment: app.php is laravels built in config file.. it there any file by spark name?

Comment: no config files with any mention of spark in the filename.

Comment: Sorry. I failed to remove a spark class from config app.php. I did that and ran composer update and spark seems to be removed...but, now somehting is awry with my views. The joys of programming!

Comment: are you doing this on production environment or development environment.. backup everything and start with fresh laravel installation in case of bugs.. just need to copy important files from backup and replace on new one

Comment: Definitely dev; only running under homestead. I'll try playing around with a new install and follow your recommendation. Thanks so much for all the conversation! I learned a good bit through the process.

Comment: You are welcome.. and good luck with it.. Dont forget to use latest version of laravel and spark :)